# Create new columns by comparing the current row's values and previous in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dummy dataset `df` as follow:

```
   year   v1   v2
0  2017  0.3  0.1
1  2018  0.1  0.1
2  2019 -0.2  0.5
3  2020  NaN -0.3
4  2021  0.8  0.0
```

or:

```
[{'year': 2017, 'v1': 0.3, 'v2': 0.1},
 {'year': 2018, 'v1': 0.1, 'v2': 0.1},
 {'year': 2019, 'v1': -0.2, 'v2': 0.5},
 {'year': 2020, 'v1': nan, 'v2': -0.3},
 {'year': 2021, 'v1': 0.8, 'v2': 0.0}]
```

I need to create two more columns `trend_v1` and `trend_v2` based on `v1` and `v2` respectively.

The logic to create new columns is this: for each column, if its current value is greater than the previous, the trend value is `increase`, if its current value is less than the previous, the trend value is `decrease`, if its current value is equal to the previous, the trend value is `equal`, if the current or previous value is `NaN`, the trend also is `NaN`.

```
   year   v1   v2  trend_v1  trend_v2
0  2017  0.3  0.1       NaN       NaN
1  2018  0.1  0.1  decrease     equal
2  2019 -0.2  0.5  decrease  increase
3  2020  NaN -0.3       NaN  decrease
4  2021  0.8  0.0       NaN  increase
```

How could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks for your help at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify columns for test trend by compare shifted values with filtered missing values:

```
cols = ['v1','v2']
arr = np.where(df[cols] < df[cols].shift(),'decrease',
      np.where(df[cols] > df[cols].shift(),'increase',
      np.where(df[cols].isna() | df[cols].shift().isna(), None, 'equal')))

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=cols, index=df.index).add_prefix('trend_'))
print (df)
   year   v1   v2  trend_v1  trend_v2
0  2017  0.3  0.1      None      None
1  2018  0.1  0.1  decrease     equal
2  2019 -0.2  0.5  decrease  increase
3  2020  NaN -0.3      None  decrease
4  2021  0.8  0.0      None  increase
```

Or:

```
cols = ['v1','v2']

m1 = df[cols] < df[cols].shift()
m2 = df[cols] > df[cols].shift()
m3 = df[cols].isna() | df[cols].shift().isna()

arr = np.select([m1, m2, m3],['decrease','increase', None], default='equal')

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=cols, index=df.index).add_prefix('trend_'))
```

EDIT:

Nice improvement is change `m3` like mentioned in comments:

```
cols = ['v1','v2']

m1 = df[cols] < df[cols].shift()
m2 = df[cols] > df[cols].shift()
m3 = df[cols] == df[cols].shift()

arr = np.select([m1, m2, m3],['decrease','increase', 'equal'], default=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, may i ask can we use `np.NaN` instead of `None`? what's the difference?

Comment: @ah bon I use None here because I want avoid convert NaN to string nan if use np.nan instead None.

Comment: The reason is trend columns with dtype `string` rather than `number`?

Comment: @ah bon exactly you are right.

Comment: Just a question, we can also use: `m3 = df[cols] == df[cols].shift(); arr = np.select([m1, m2, m3],['decrease','increase', 'equal'], default='None')`, right?

Comment: @ahbon - Agree, you are right.